# How to create Omniture SiteCatalyst trial account?

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are in the evaluation phase of integrating Omniture SiteCatalyst with our website, but I cannot find any link to create Omniture SiteCatalyst trial account.

I have found the below link for site catalyst login:
http://www.esomniture.com/es_c_login.html

But this link only for existing users. Sign up for new users is not there.

I know that Omniture site catalyst is a paid service. Do they provide trail accounts for evaluation purpose?

Any help would be highly appriciated..

Thank You,
Raj

Comment: offtopic, and question should be asked directly to Omniture.

Answer (score 3):

The way Omniture works, is that everything will go through a sales engineer or client rep. The only way you'll get a free trial is if the sales engineer sets one up for you, so I'd suggest contacting their sales department.

Answer (score 1):

Omniture is a suite of products aimed at the Enterprise/big end of town, they're not really aimed at the little guy. The benefits of it over other web analytics tools are directed at this market..things like integration with other data systems and test and target etc.

So they don't do free trials, they're not a "freemium" business model.

To be honest, a smaller-medium site wouldn't find it as as exciting or sexy as some of the other newer, more nimble solutions on the market.

Answer (score 1):

I just Found out this URL:

https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/forum/reporting/how-to-create-omniture-sitecatalyst-trial-account

Guess this should help. I am also in the process of creating one. Let's see how this goes.